# How to determine span index of grid layout manager?

Tags: android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I'am using `RecyclerView` and `GridLayoutManager` with 5 span count in my layout.

How to determine span index of item in `GridLayoutManager` by the item position?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally i found it!
The layout param of root view holder item is `GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams` and has `getSpanIndex()` method.

```
RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = m_RecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position);
if (viewHolder != null) {
    GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams lp = (GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) viewHolder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
    int spanIndex = lp.getSpanIndex();
}
```